# Setting up salesforce push notification for Android using SDK

Tags: java, android, push-notification, salesforce

I would like to integrate push notification on Android application using Salesforce. I have integretaed Salesforce SDK on the Android applicaiton. Calling `PushMessaging.register` function i have registered and initalized the **FirebaseOptions** by setting up the `ApiKey, ProjectId, ApplicationId, GcmSenderId`. On Salesforce platform under setup-> search -> user -> select user and under view `Mobile Push Registrations` i could not find the registered device listed. On the Connected App section i tried **Send a Test Notification** and same result i couldn't lookup for the device here again[image: Added the attachment].

Can some one help me out the step that i would missed setting up?

Answer (score 1):

Put your FCM Token directly in receipt one thing I am also struggling is the payload and there is no documentation